# How can I add a logic for my shopify store checkout button whenever the customer uses it for checkout, the price of item automatically increases 12%?

Tags: javascript, html, logic, shopify, liquid

I'm managing a Shopify Store for a company selling pre-owned mobile phones.
We recently integrated Breadpay Financing API for checkout but Breadpay Financing charges us a fee for every item sold via their Checkout System.

Now we want to include some kind of Logic where **"Whenever a customer uses Breadpay checkout, the price for the item they are purchasing automatically gets 12% increased"**

I'm kind of stuck including this feature in the website,

I'd really appreciate the help I can get.

Thank you!

I took ChatGPT help but to be honest, I'm not a developer and I don't understand JS etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the checkout process, you need to use Shopify's Script Editor app or an app that provides similar functionality.

Here are the steps to follow:

1. Log in to your Shopify admin panel and go to the Apps section.
2. Click on the Script Editor app and select the Create script button.
3. Choose the Script type as "Line item" and give it a name like "Price Increase Script".
4. In the Script code section, paste the following code:

   subtotal = Input.cart.subtotal_price
   markup = subtotal * 0.12

   Input.cart.line_items.each do |line_item|
   Input.cart.add_line_item(
   variant_id: line_item.variant_id,
   quantity: line_item.quantity,
   properties: line_item.properties,
   price: line_item.price + markup
   )
   end

   Output.cart = Input.cart
5. Save the script and enable it.
   Test the checkout process to see if the price is being increased by 12% correctly.

-Once you have created the script using the Script Editor app, it will run automatically during the checkout process and modify the price of the items in the cart as desired.

Try this if this work